# select2, mvc and html5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, mobile, jquery-select2

We are using select2 as a dropdown in our website. The website is now going responsive and while the select2 is an awesome control, it does not turn into the native control on mobile using html5. 
i.e.: the html5 tag date will bring up the native mobile calendar, which is different from android to iOS, and it is much more user-friendly. We would like to have the same feature with our dropdowns. Since select2 does not include the select tag in its markup, this is not possible. 
Does anynody have a suggestion to what control would satisfy these needs? Used programming environment is asp.net MVC
Thank you

--edit--
select2 typical markup:

```
<div class="select2-container" id="s2id_Step1GeneralInfo_IsGWEInclusive" style="width: 100%;">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="return false;" class="select2-choice" tabindex="-1">
       <span><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="labelSelectedOption"></td>
                        <td class="selectedOption">inclusive</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
             </table>
       </span>
       <abbr class="select2-search-choice-close" style="display: none;"></abbr>   
       <div><b></b></div>
    </a><input class="select2-focusser select2-offscreen" type="text">
 </div>
```

---normal select markup [now html5 ready]---

```
<select name="select">
   <option value="value1">Value 1</option> 
   <option value="value2" selected>Value 2</option>
   <option value="value3">Value 3</option>
</select>
```

the second markup reacts on mobile devices by popping up the device's control. The first one does not

Comment: know its your first question posting here, it typically helps to post snippets,jsfiddles, pictures, or anything that helps the knowledge base here understand your problem and give direction for a solution

Comment: I edited the post adding typical markup examples. However, I don't think the question deserves a -1: anybody familiar with html5, mobile and select2 (hence the tags) would have an understanding of what the "problem" is. I'm simply asking for a suggestion on dropdown controls here.

Comment: oh and for the records: this is my second question here. The first one, since more specific for a certain control/problem and not a generic request for a hint, had all the snippets it needed. It would perhaps be of use to check before downvoting

Comment: if this helps any, this is not really a asp.net mvc issue of selecting the correct control, its an ongoing bug/discussion within select2 https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2/issues/1541

Comment: thank you. I bumped into that bug and it does has a workaround. But while it solves the keyboard problem, it does not bring up the native select control on a mobile device. I don't think select2 will ever do, due to its inherent structure and the way it designs the markup (which from a select gets turned basically into a table, hence the problem)